# SQL JOIN AS400 from table #temp

Tags: sql-server, db2, ibm-midrange

I want to make a dynamic join between sql and as400, of this type:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(AS400_link,'SELECT                                  
        AS400.CAMPO1
        ,AS400.CAMPO2
        ,AS400.CAMPO3
        ,AS400.CAMPO4                                           
    FROM AS400_FILE AS AS400
    INNERT JOIN #TAB_TEMP AS TEMP ON
        TEMP.CAMPO1 = AS400.CAMPO1
    ')

DROP TABLE #TAB_TEMP
```

if I run it:

OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "AS400_link" returned message "SQL0113: Nome #TAB_TEMP non consentito.
Causa  . . . : #TAB_TEMP...

some solution?
Thank you

Comment: you van not access Temp tables in opnequery

Comment: as I imagined ...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is more like

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(AS400_link,'SELECT 
        AS400.CAMPO1
        ,AS400.CAMPO2
        ,AS400.CAMPO3
        ,AS400.CAMPO4                                           
    FROM AS400_FILE') AS AS400
    INNER JOIN #TAB_TEMP AS TEMP ON
        TEMP.CAMPO1 = AS400.CAMPO1
```

Don't expect it to perform well.

Comment: Thanks, so I know it works. My problem is filtering the records on as400 since there are so many.
I hope I explained

Comment: Your remote server cannot magically reach out and poke into your local temporary table; to join a remote and a local table you have to either ship the remote table to the local machine or somehow send filter conditions to the remote server explicitly as part of the query, not as a reference to a local table (which is not accessible remotely).